# What is this tree that displays sycamore like characteristics but appears to be too small?

Tags: species-identification, botany, trees

I have been wondering about this tree:

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

It's bark/leaves make me think it's a sycamore, but it seems too puny. I don't think they'd plant a sycamore there... What is it?

The tree is in a park/residential area in Orange County, Southern California.

Reasons I think it looks Sycamorish:

- Alternate leaves
- 3 lobes
- Mottled/patchy/peely bark

https://www.thoughtco.com/identify-maple-sycamore-yellow-poplar-sweetgum-leaves-1343480

Comment: When dealing with species ID, Africans indicate the country and the continent, Americans indicate the county and an abbreviation to indicate a region within the state (now corrected) $\ddot \smile$ I personnaly did not know SoCal meant South California. +1 otherwise!

Comment: probably the london planetree. that is my best guess

Comment: Adding photos of bark, and fruits/flowers if available might help.

Comment: "Mottled/patchy/peely bark" suggests me https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platanus

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is very likely a [**London planetree**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platanus_%C3%97_acerifolia) (*Platanus × acerifolia*), a hybrid species of *Platanus* often planted in cities.

[image: London Planetree leaves]

<sup>Source: [Cuyamaca College](https://www.cuyamaca.edu/academics/departments/oh/plants/files/Thumbnail_Pages/Platanus_acerifolia.aspx)</sup>

[image]

<sup>Source: [Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:London_Planetree_bark_detail.jpg)</sup>

The tree is a hybrid between [*Platanus orientalis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platanus_orientalis) and [*Platanus occidentalis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platanus_occidentalis) (the sycamore tree), and has characteristics intermediate between the two species.

- Smaller (heights of only 20-30 m vs 30-40+ m for parent species).
- More deeply lobed leaf than *P. occidentalis* but less so than *P. orientalis*
- Seed balls typically two per stem (one in *P. occidentalis*, 3-6 in *P. orientalis*)

  - Note: seed "balls" = aggregate of many small seed-like fruits called achenes
- VERY OFTEN PLANTED IN URBAN AREAS

  - Because it's very tolerant of atmospheric pollution and root compaction

Description:

- Leaves: alternate, simple, 3-5 lobes, maple-shaped, 10–20 cm long, 12–25 cm wide
- Bark: pale grey-green (or brown), smooth and peeling (sometimes not peeling)